# How to add a preface chapter to a book that appears before all chapters and is not numbered as a chapter?

Tags: memoir, chapters

I just wrote the preface to my book and I made it a `\chapter`, but now the preface is `Chapter 1` of the book, which is not what I desire. I am using the `memoir` document class. Does anyone know how to make this preface chapter not really be a chapter?

Answer (score 33):

A preface is usually set in the front matter. If you say

```
\frontmatter
<front matter>

\chapter{Preface}
<text of the preface>

\mainmatter
<main matter>
```

the Preface will be set as an unnumbered chapter.

Answer (score 7):

Use `\chapter*` instead of `\chapter`.

Comment: @Peteris No, it doesn't. The `*` following some commands denotes a "variation" of that command (what is varied depends on the command). Beware that a chapter introduced with `\chapter*{Title}` won't automatically go in the table of contents.

Comment: @Peteris: I would *love* to see an actual example where `\chapter*` produces a chapter number in memoir or any other class.

Comment: @Peteris: Remember to use `\chapter{Preface}` in the `\frontmatter`, so the preface will automatically go in the ToC.

Comment: @Peteris: To get rid of the goofy section numbers in your preface, do the same trick with your sections (and subsections, etc) in your preface that you did with chapter: Use the starred version of those commands: `\section*`, `\subsection*`, etc.

Comment: And to get the preface into the table of contents (if that is your desire), you may need to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}`.

Comment: Why, moving it into the `\frontmatter` automatically remove the sectional numbering, so it just works. BTW: using the `\addcontentsline` solution will not work correctly if you are using `hyperref`, in that case always use a `\phantomsection` before issuing the `\addcontentsline` otherwise the hyperlinks do not have anything to hook on to.