# How to give two \book{}s each its own Preface?

Tags: memoir, chapters, book-design, front-matter

I have a book which contains two books, each having their own preface. Here's the structure:

```
\book{An exhortation to virtue}

    \frontmatter

        \chapter{Preface}

        ...

    \mainmatter

        \chapter{This is the first chapter of the first book}

        ...

        \chapter{This is the second chapter of the first book}

        ...

\book{An instruction on virtue}

    \frontmatter

        \chapter{Preface}

        ...

    \mainmatter

        \chapter{This is the first chapter of the second book}

        ...

        \chapter{This is the second chapter of the second book}

        ...
```

This structure is based on [this answer's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19809/78860) to create a Preface by using `\chapter` inside of `\frontmatter`.

Obviously this structure won't work because it assumes two separate front-matters.

So what's another way to create two prefaces for two books within the same book?

Another goal is that this book should have a single Table of Contents containing both books in their entirety.

Comment: Instead of posting the image (which isn't actually that important to the question) create a small document that shows the structure of what you have already.  It doesn't need to be fancy, just enough to show the `\book` structure you are using.

Comment: @AlanMunn Okay I'll edit it right now, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @sdegutis No, this is a bit too schematic. Make a complete compilable document showing what you have (without the content).  So you want each book to have its own frontmatter part, with e.g. roman numbering.

Comment: What are the special characteristics that make certain chapters a "preface"? Lack of chapter number? special formatting in the TOC? page numbers in "roman" rather than "arabic"? other things?

Comment: @jon All of those, plus chapter numbering starts over at Chapter 1 after each Preface.

Comment: That'll almost work as is if you add `\documentclass{memoir}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use

```
\counterwithin*{chapter}{book}
```

Then each time `\book` is used, chapter will be reset to zero.

Comment: (+1) I hope you will not mind that I changed my answer to integrate this rather than `\apptocmd`. If you object, you can use my code to create a complete example and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @cfr no problem. Just leave it. I'm currently at a tablet so large examples like your is not something I'm going to do on this device

Answer (score 1):

Memoir does very nearly the right thing with the code you posted. Originally, I was not sure if it has a way to reset the chapter numbers per book, but I couldn't find it and couldn't think, so used `etoolbox` to patch the command. However, [daleif's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266381/) is much better and can easily be integrated into the code I was using. Other than that, I just changed your dots to Kant and added a table of contents:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\book{An exhortation to virtue}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\kant[1]

\mainmatter

\chapter{This is the first chapter of the first book}

\kant[1]

\chapter{This is the second chapter of the first book}

\kant[1]

\book{An instruction on virtue}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\kant[1]

\mainmatter

\chapter{This is the first chapter of the second book}

\kant[1]

\chapter{This is the second chapter of the second book}

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Memoir Kant]

Comment: Thanks. This technically works, but I can't help but feel it's a bit hacky. I'll wait a day or two to give others a chance to chime in also.

Comment: @sdegutis Waiting for other answers is wise. But I don't see why you'd think using Memoir 'a bit hacky'. Or do you mean the use of `etoolbox` to reset the counter? You should be able to combine this with [daleif's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266381/) to avoid that.

Comment: @sdegutis Please see edit.